# robot framework selenium check link

Tags: selenium, robotframework

how can i run keyword only if specific link is exist in the page,
and if the link not exist continue the test as usual ?
I tried like this but it does not work

```
${Result}=  Page Should Contain Link  ${link}
run keyword if  '${Result}'=='PASS'  Get Rid of Messages
```

and the link exist  in the page

Comment: How the html code of element looks like? Please read [mcve] and [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your post accordingly.

Comment: <div class="messageLinkStyle"><a>Close these 2 messages</a></div>

Comment: and i give the ${link} value of the xpath of <a>Close these 2 messages</a>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are looking for is the [Run Keyword And Return Status](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Run%20Keyword%20And%20Return%20Status) keyword from the BuiltIn library.

> Runs the given keyword with given arguments and returns the status as
> a Boolean value.
>
> This keyword returns Boolean True if the keyword that is executed
> succeeds and False if it fails. This is useful, for example, in
> combination with Run Keyword If. If you are interested in the error
> message or return value, use Run Keyword And Ignore Error instead.

```
${passed}=    Run Keyword And Return Status    Page Should Contain Link    ${link}
Run Keyword If    ${passed}   Get Rid of Messages
```